# How can I identify a question from a text file in python?

Tags: kivy, python-3.6

I want to take text from a doc file, and out of this text, I want to separate out the questions.

How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes a question different from any other line?

Probably because it ends with a question mark `?`

So, you may be able to tell that a line is a question by testing it ends with a question mark.

```
line.endswith('?')
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I though have been busy with something else but I am going to try it now.